# Csharp extract data form a .csv file

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader, streamwriter.write

I'm looking for a short code to give the user the possibilities to choose the city matching with the zip code he types on console.
I have a csv file were all the France zip code are present.
An example:

- type the zip code : 75000

1 - paris 1er arrondissement 
2 - paris 2eme arrondissement
3 - paris 3eme arrondissement
4 - paris 4eme arrondissement
5 - paris 5eme arrondissement
6 - paris 6eme arrondissement
7 - paris 7eme arrondissement
8 - paris 8eme  arrondissement
9 - paris 9eme arrondissement
...

the user after that has to chose 1 , 2 ,... or 9.
and this entry from the csv should be written in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a file:

```
string line = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```